# Can't seem to replace the string

Tags: ruby, string

I want this string `"THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG"` to have the spaces of this string `"QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD"` or whatever special character as long as it replaces the first string characters with the second string character. I want to replace the spaced string with the first string.

Comment: You can split the second string, then for each word count the chars, then parse the first string with the acquired length and each time at a space to it.

Comment: Can you explicitly state what result string you want?  it's not clear from your description.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers especially @sawa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chars = "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG".chars
"QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD".gsub(/\w/){chars.shift}
```

or

```
chars = "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG"
"QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD".gsub(/\w/){chars.slice!(0)}
```

or

```
chars = "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG"
"QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD".gsub(/\w/).with_index{|_, i| chars[i]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
target = "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG"
source = "QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD"
new_target = source.split(' ').map { |partial| target.slice!(0,partial.length) }.join(' ') 
new_target
```

Updated code thanks to comment by @bosskovic

Comment: probably even easier to use a regex, but my knowledge of it is limited.

Comment: nice; maybe you should map instead of iterating with "each", and then do a join, it would be cleaner.

Comment: new_target = source.split(' ').map { |partial| target.slice!(0,partial.length) }.join(' ')

Comment: Nice, thanks! I still have a lot to learn I see :)

Comment: Thanks but I won't be using this in my final work but learned a lot from it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPSOVERTHELAZYDOG"
s2 = "QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD"
char = ' '

s2.split.each_with_index do |_count, index|
  char_location = s2.index(char)
  s.insert(char_location + index, char) if char_location
  s2.sub!(char, '')
end

=> THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Comment: The gusy above provided me with simpler answers but thanks for your time and answer. Cheers